# Confusion in solving linear system by $LU$ factorization

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In solving system of linear equation $Ax = b$ by $LU$ factorization why we take diagonal elements of lower triangular matrix $L$ or upper triangular matrix $U$ as $1$ only. I understand that to get the unique solution by $LU$ factorization we have to fix either diagonal elements of $L$ or of diagonal elements of $U$. Can't I take $2$ as the fix diagonal elements?

Thanks for the kind help.

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the comment. In Crout or Doolittle.

Comment: @Moo Thank you very much. I saw the result. However, it seems to me difficult to understand the theorem.

Comment: Yes, you can. Taking them as $1$ is just for convenience.

Comment: @KittyL Once upon a time, division was a relatively expensive operation to perform (both for humans and machines). So taking a diagonal 1 in $L$ or $U$ was not just for convenience but for the sake of improving the performance of the system solutions.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: I see! Thank you!

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you for the reply. Please write your comment as an answer. Also, if instead of 1 I am taking any other number will I get the same factorization?